# How to backup SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm getting an error when doing a backup of SQL Server on my local machine to a server machine, but if I try my query my local database, it works. Can you help me figure out the problem?

```
BACKUP DATABASE 'DBName' TO DISK 'FILENAME'
```

I'm getting this error when I'm doing a backup from LOCAL - MAIN:

> Cannot open backup device 'path'. Device Error or Device off-line. BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

But when I'm doing it on my local machine it works perfectly.

Comment: The path of the backup file has to be accessible to the instance doing the backup.  You generally won't be able to backup a remote instance to your local machine.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/207187/you-cannot-back-up-databases-to-a-network-drive-if-your-account-have-n

Comment: so you need to do it in a server machine instead of local machine to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a backup of a SQL Server database, you have to keep in mind that the client sends the command/query to perform that backup to the SQL Server instance. So all the paths specified have to be regarded from the server's point of view. Not the client's. So when making SQL Server backups, local paths like `'C:\Backup\MyDatabase.BAK'` will point to the server's C-drive, not your own client's C-drive.

You could make a database backup to a network location using a UNC path (something like `'\\SERVER\Share\Backup'`), but you have to be sure that the server (and the user account that is used to run the SQL Server instance on your server) has sufficient access privileges to that network location.

And - again - if you want to use drive mappings to network paths/aliases, they have to be defined and accessible for the SQL Server instance's user account too; perhaps it's best is to always use full path names for creating database backups on a network location.

Hope this helps a little.

**Edit**

I also always use the following syntax for the backup command:

```
BACKUP DATABASE 'DBName' TO DISK = 'FILENAME'
```

Note the equal sign after `DISK`. Without it, you will probably get a syntax error. (I tested it shortly and I got a syntax error in SQL Server 2017.)

Comment: i forgot the equal sign lol sorry anyway thank you for your answers guys